# Do bots open files and use bandwidth

Tags: html, server, bots, robots.txt

We are trying to lower our bandwidth usage and after breaking down which files are using the most bandwidth we are a bit confused. Although we haven't formally promoted our podcast site, the MP3 files (~10MB each) are using between 1-2 GB of Bandwidth so far this month alone. I've done some testing with Google Analytics that would use some bandwidth but I don't think it would use that much.

Do bots crawl MP3/MP4 files and add to their bandwidth usage? Most the files were 206 status code.

Comment: Do you have access to your server logs? If so, you should be able to tell who is accessing the files. Many hosts provide stats packages for precisely that.

Comment: The main logging program is AWStats which I tells me that bots are crawling and using bandwidth but it doesn't break it down by file. It does help to see the bandwidth usage of the bots though so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly a possibility. You can add a robots.txt file to your site and add something like this to prevent them from scanning (if they did so).

`User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/*.mp4`

Comment: Great thank you, I will try and add that to the robots file and just see if things get better